# Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a selection of sql code that I keep getting an 'Incorrect syntax' error on.

I cannot see what is causing the issue.

Can anyone point out the obvious to me?  I maybe have been staring at the code for too long to see it now!!

My code is :-

```
DECLARE @CostCatID AS Int

SELECT * FROM vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt
WHERE PACOSTCATID IN (@CostCatID)
AND (DOC_DATE &gt;= @DateFrom) 
AND (DOC_DATE  &lt;= @DateTo)
order by 1
```

and the full error message I get is:-

> Incorrect syntax near ';'

I know it is going to be obvious to most people but for the life of me in my tired state I cannot get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

(all work is being done in sql Server Management Studio 2005)

Comment: why the metachars &gt; and &lt; ? have you tryed with < >?

Comment: Thanks people.  I took the code from a previous version of the report that wasn't working.  I am in the process of rebuilding it.  Should have spotted that one.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&gt;` and `&lt;`? Why are you encoding `>` and `<`? There's your problem. Try:

```
DECLARE @CostCatID AS Int

SELECT * FROM vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt
WHERE PACOSTCATID IN (@CostCatID)
AND (DOC_DATE >= @DateFrom) 
AND (DOC_DATE <= @DateTo)
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `&gt;` and `&lt;`, you need to use `>` and `<`

```
DECLARE @CostCatID AS Int

SELECT * FROM vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt
WHERE PACOSTCATID IN (@CostCatID)
AND (DOC_DATE >= @DateFrom) 
AND (DOC_DATE  <= @DateTo)
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `&gt;` and `&lt;`: did you copy from a web page?

```
DECLARE @CostCatID AS Int

SELECT * FROM vwREP_GP_ContractProjectPurchaseRpt
WHERE PACOSTCATID IN (@CostCatID)
AND (DOC_DATE >= @DateFrom) 
AND (DOC_DATE <= @DateTo)
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For once, the SQL error message is quite helpful:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'

and you have the string `&gt;=` unquoted in you code.

I think you meant to use `>=` and `<=` instead.